# Application with nodejs and express, can't loggin ios Iphone

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, express

Application works in every desktop I tested and mobile phone, just not working log in in ios (iphone 6, 8)

My application:
- nodejs
- express
- mongodb
- not using passport

I can't give more details because I can't see in logs any problem, just repeated and try to access but nothing:

```
GET /usuario/ 302 2.758 ms - 70
GET /mis-anuncios 200 5.213 ms - 5600
POST /mis-anuncios 302 90.279 ms - 62
GET /usuario/ 200 101.493 ms - 18969
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that req.session is saved when loggin (in controller), but when I make redirect to aut route it is not traveling through the middleware for controlling that it is authenticated.

Anyone has had this problem?

I checked cookies and delete cache in safari.
I also test in mozilla and chrome. 
With ingonito too.

It goes again and again to log in form without password or email errors.

Comment: It could be that some of the `request` value returned `undefined`? You can try to purposely return query error and see the query whether all the value from `request.body.xx` etc. is giving the correct value or not

Comment: @tcadidot0 it looks like don't save session. I console.log in auth middleware req.session.currentUser and it is not auth. Why?

Comment: I'm not really sure and so far I only found [one question almost similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888214/express-session-not-saving-for-ipad) yours but it doesn't have accepted answer yet. Maybe you can get some idea from there?

Comment: req body
[Object: null prototype] { email: 'email@gmail.com', password: 'pass' }
something interesting, it one picture (only one) doesn't show just in iphone